# One-to-many relationship is sharepoint, populate dropdown list from another library

Tags: document-library

is it possible to replicate a one-to-many relationship in sharepoint lists.

Scenario: I've two libraries - A and B. All documents in library B must belong to one document in the document A. So, when I'm adding a new document in library B, I want to be able to have a dropdown list which is populated from the title of documents in library A.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Lookup column in library B that points to the Title field of library A.  When a new item is uploaded, users will then see a drop down list and display all the values of existing items in library A as possible selections.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you have a good start based on PirateErics response. I might add that if you are looking for a cascading relationship between your Lists look at spservices from Marc Anderson.  Here is a [link](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: hey thanks for the additional comment. will look in to it tooo.